# Error when I execute trigger code in MySQL Workbench

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures, triggers

I am working in a trigger but I get an error when I execute the code:

```
CREATE TRIGGER my_trigger
AFTER INSERT
ON reservation
FOR EACH ROW
EXECUTE PROCEDURE update_available_space NEW.date_shift, NEW.start_hour_shift;
```

Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'PROCEDURE update_available_space NEW.date_shift, NEW.start_hour_shift' at line 5

Someone knows which is the error?

Comment: Have you double-checked the [`CREATE TRIGGER`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-trigger.html) syntax? You may need `BEGIN` and `END` around the thing you want to run, the `trigger_body`.

Comment: @tadman actually I try that but it doesn't work yet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A stored procedure is not executed by EXECUTE PROCEDURES

In  mysql You call the procedure

```
CREATE TRIGGER my_trigger
AFTER INSERT
ON reservation
FOR EACH ROW
 CALL update_available_space( NEW.date_shift, NEW.start_hour_shift);
```

But rememmber you can not change the same table in a procedure, which triggert the TRIGGER